# json path not working as expected when used with get_json_object

Tags: pyspark, jsonpath

**TLDR;** The following JSON path isn't working for me when used with `pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object`.

```
$.Blocks[?(@.Type=='LINE')].Confidence
```

**Long version...**

I want to group by arrays within a single row

For example, for the structure below

```
root
|--id: string
|--payload: string
```

the value of `payload` is a String representing a block of json that looks like the structure below

```
{
        "Blocks": [
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 90
            },
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 98
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 97
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 89
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to aggregate all of the confidence by type so we get the following new column...

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "payload": "..."
    "confidence": [
        {
            "Type": "WORD",
            "Confidence": [
                99,
                99
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "PAGE",
            "Confidence": [
                97,
                89
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "LINE",
            "Confidence": [
                90,
                98
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To do this I plan on using `get_json_object(...)` to extract confidences for each type of block.

For example...

```
get_json_object(col("payload"), "$.Blocks[?(@.Type=='LINE')].Confidence")
```

But `$.Blocks[?(@.Type=='LINE')].Confidence` keeps returning `null`. Why is that?

I verified the json path works by testing on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/# against the sample `payload` json above and got the following result...

```
[
   90,
   98
]
```

If using the path above isn't an option how would one go about aggregating this?

Below is the full code sample. I expect the first `.show()` to print out `[90, 98]` in the confidence column.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object, col


def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test_session').getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (
            12345,  # id
            """
{
        "Blocks": [
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 90
            },
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 98
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 97
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 89
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            }
        ]
    }

            """  # payload
        )
    ],
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("payload", StringType(), True)
            ])
    )
    
    # this prints out null (why?)
    df.withColumn("confidence", get_json_object(col("payload"), "$.Blocks[?(@.Type=='LINE')].Confidence")).show()
    
    # this prints out the correct values, [90,98,99,97,89,99]
    df.withColumn("confidence", get_json_object(col("payload"), "$.Blocks[*].Confidence")).show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I have found a more complex way around this, which is to just use udt and manually parse the json payload, with another jsonpath package. Still interested in why the proposed json path isn't working and what I can do to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official document on how Spark parse JSON path, but based on [its source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L56), looks like it does not support `@` as current object. In fact it supports very limited syntax:

```
// parse `[*]` and `[123]` subscripts
// parse `.name` or `['name']` child expressions
// child wildcards: `..`, `.*` or `['*']`
```

So if you're open with another approach, here it is with pre-defined schema and functions like `from_json`, `explode`, `collect_list`:

```py
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('Blocks', T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
        T.StructField('Type', T.StringType()),
        T.StructField('Confidence', T.IntegerType())
    ])))
])

(df
    .withColumn('json', F.from_json('payload', schema))
    .withColumn('block', F.explode('json.blocks'))
    .select('id', 'block.*')
    .groupBy('id', 'Type')
    .agg(F.collect_list('Confidence').alias('confidence'))
    .show(10, False)
)

# +-----+----+----------+
# |id   |Type|confidence|
# +-----+----+----------+
# |12345|PAGE|[97, 89]  |
# |12345|WORD|[99, 99]  |
# |12345|LINE|[90, 98]  |
# +-----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you! this explains a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since get_json_object() do not support @, jsonpath_ng python module can be used to find the exact value of input json path.

```
import json
import sys,time
sys.path.insert(0,"/opt/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/")
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
val='''{
        "Blocks": [
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 90
            },
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 98
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 97
            },
            {
                "Type": "PAGE",
                "Confidence": 89
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
            }
        ]
    }'''
json_data=json.loads(val)
query=[x.value for x in parser.parse("$.Blocks[?(@.Type=='LINE')].Confidence").find(json_data)]
var=json.dumps(query)
#var=var[1:-1]
print(var)
```

> > [90, 98]

If you want output without [] then uncomment var=var[1:-1] in above code.